# Parse error sending data from JSON to Django

Tags: javascript, django, json

so I'm trying to pass some basic JSON data from javascript to a django view.

Here's my code right now:

```
   var Data = { 
        Meds: [] 
   };

   for(var x = 0; x < pt.meds_arr.length; x++)
   {
       MedList.Meds.push({"Med": MedData[x]});
   };

   $.ajax({
            url: "django/path",
            dataType: "application/json",
            data: Data,
            success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
            },
            error: function(err1, err2) {
                alert(err1 + err2);
            }

   });
```

Alright, so firebug shows me that this is the data being sent:

```
Meds[0][Med]    Med1

Meds[1][Med]    Med2
```

Which seems right to me.

The django view is:

```
def query(request):
data = request.GET;

if(data is None):
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()

return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json');
```

The problem is, Django is apparently not handling the data correctly. I'm getting a parse error. In firebug, the response that I get back is:

```
Meds[1][Med]Meds[0][Med]
```

Anyone have any idea what may be up? It looks like the data isn't being treated as JSON at some end?

Comment: what is the value of `request.GET`?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I go about checking? The value is in python and I can't exactly print anything since its part of the django view.

Comment: literally type: `print request.GET` in the Python code

Comment: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, you can put a debbuger in your `query` function.  THen you can inspect request.GET

Answer (score 0):

Try this view:

```
def query(request):
    data = request.GET;

    if(data is None):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    #use json.dumps()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json');
```